# Svelte - object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, typescript, null, svelte

I'm trying to make this [Smooth Scrolling Navigation](https://codepen.io/bramus/embed/ExaEqMJ?height=687&theme-id=default&default-tab=result&user=bramus&slug-hash=ExaEqMJ&pen-title=Smooth%20Scrolling%20Sticky%20ScrollSpy%20Navigation&name=cp_embed_4#result-box) work in Svelte. But still, have this TypeScript error **object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)**.
I realized that this error is because TypeScript thinks that this element may have a value of null.
So I have to declare what is this element with an `if` statement or use the exclamation mark operator `!` (like this is not null).
I've tried numerous possibilities for both solutions but still without success.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7006d7890b964928b8f72622a3d067ac?version=3.42.5) of full code in svelte, where is visible that `IntersectionObserver`doesn't work.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let id;
    
    onMount(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
                    
                    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                        document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`)    //error
                            .parentElement    //error
                            .classList
                            .add('active');
                    } else {
                        document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`)    //error
                            .parentElement    //error
                            .classList
                            .remove('active');
                    };
            });

            document.querySelectorAll('section[id]').forEach((section) => {
                observer.observe(section);
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Original code is from [Bram](https://www.bram.us/). Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Unrelated to your `object is possibly 'null'` issue, but I think you're still inside the `IntersectionObserver` constructor's callback when you do the `document.querySelectorAll('section[id]')`, so the observer never gets to observe anything and its callback would never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES! I did it.

A functional version of TOC (Table of Content) for Svelte with an adjustable class that shows and tracks an active item in the TOC list according to content (heading, text) in the viewport.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

let id
let element
    
    onMount(() => {
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                    id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
                    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                        element = document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`);
                        if (element && element.parentElement )  {
                            element.parentElement.classList.add('active');
                        }
                    } else {
                        element = document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`)
                        if (element && element.parentElement )  {
                            element.parentElement.classList.remove('active');
                        }
                    };
                });
            });
        // Track all sections that have an `id` applied
        document.querySelectorAll('section[id]').forEach((section) => {
        observer.observe(section);
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

This is an  adjusted version of the [original code](https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/ExaEqMJ) for Svelte. The creator is [Bram](https://www.bram.us/) check his blog.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend either not letting TypeScript check JS code or actually using TypeScript.

The former should be configurable via the `tsconfig.json` option [`checkJs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs).

For the latter, you have to use [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) (see documentation) and declare the script language:

```html
<script lang="ts"> ...
```

Otherwise you *cannot* use TS-specific syntax like `!` or type assertions.

---

To pacify possibly `null`/`undefined` errors, you can always use if statements, but you need to extract a variable containing the relevant value:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('...');
if (element) {
  // element will be defined here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have defined `<script lang="ts">` in my code but forgot to write it into the code in question. When I installed SvelteKit I accepted the option with TypeScript, so I thought that TS is supported. I tried to turn off `checkJS` and still it doesn't work then I tried put in `strictNullChecks:false` but it is still unfunctional. Although I did it in `jsconfig.json` I am not sure if it is the same but Svelte have this file. I will try to extract a variable containing value ... also I didn't know about `svelte-preprocess` so I have to check the documentation. Thank you H.B

Comment: I don't really think that recommending the user to turn off TS will do any good for them, especially in this case as it can lead to actual errors on their app.

Comment: @MarcosSandrini: I was only talking about the JS checking feature which is not that great as you cannot use TS syntax to fix errors that require the expressiveness of TS.

Comment: @H.B. alright, fair point. But that can be misinterpreted, like, if that's the first thing you say on your answer, some people less patient to read it through may take that as the main advice.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```js
document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`)
```

The result of this expression can be null, like, it can find nothing. TS says, very wisely, that you have to mind that or your app can fail, and maybe transform this into some expression where the null case is accounted for. One suggestion:

```js
const element = document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`)
if (element && element.parentElement) {
  element.parentElement.classList.add('active');
}
```

This way, you take the `null` case into account. Also, I think that the `document.querySelectorAll('section[id]')...` line should be outside of the `new IntersectionObserver ...` block, as noted by @Desjardins.

EDIT: added one conditional there. Thanks @Desjardins.

Comment: Thank you Marcos, but still can not figure out the final structure. I defined the line `const element ... ` and then change `if` statement to this `if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0 && element) {element.parentElement.classList.add('active'); } else if (element) {element.parentElement.classList.remove('active');};` but without success. Am I missing something?

Comment: `Node.parentElement` can be null as well, so you would also need to check that for null in order to avoid the TypeScript error. But keep in mind that this is just the TypeScript error—the IntersectionObserver issue is still there.

Comment: Added one conditional there, to take into account the very useful comment above.